# PySide browser in a separate process

Tags: python, qt, inheritance, processing, pyside

I trying to write a simple parser, which checks some web pages and if content on these pages is changed, then script sends url to the headless webkit browser which runs using PySide binding to Qt and makes a screenshot. I want this browser always running in the background separate process waiting for url to appear in queue. As soon as url comes, it makes screenshot, saves it and then returns to waiting.

I try to implement this behavior with this code(i cut the parser part):

```
import multiprocessing
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from PySide import QtGui, QtWebKit, QtCore

class Browser(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, queue_in, queue_out):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        QtWebKit.QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.queue_out = queue_out
        self.queue_in = queue_in
        self.setViewportSize(QtCore.QSize(900, 900))
        self.mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.Vertical, QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.mainFrame().loadFinished.connect(self._makeScreenshot)
        self.makeScreenshotOf()

    def makeScreenshotOf(self):
        self.mainFrame().setUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromEncoded(self.queue_in.get()))

    def _makeScreenshot(self):
        image = QtGui.QImage(self.viewportSize(), QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(image)
        self.mainFrame().render(painter)
        painter.end()
        file_name = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S-%f") + ".png"
        image.save(file_name)
        self.queue_out.put(file_name)
        self.makeScreenshotOf()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    queue_in = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue_out = multiprocessing.Queue()
    t = threading.Thread(target = Browser, args = (queue_in, queue_out))
    t.start()
    queue_in.put(url)
```

The problem is that on the first run process successfully stays on hold, awaiting url to appear in queue, but as soon as it gets url, process just stops, ignoring Qt connection

```
self.mainFrame().loadFinished.connect(self._makeScreenshot)
```

The thing is that if i directly inherit from Process

```
class Browser(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, queue_in, queue_out):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue_out = queue_out
        self.queue_in = queue_in
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.browser = QtWebKit.QWebPage()
        ...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue_in = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue_out = multiprocessing.Queue()
    b = Browser(queue_in, queue_out)
```

Then connection is not ignored and all works perfectly, but as a side effect `self.queue_in.get()` invoked in a Browser process also blocks main process (if queue is empty).

Questions:

1. Why the Qt connection is not working in the first case and working in the other?
2. Why in the second case queue.get() blocks the main process? How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that call to app.exec_() was essential. Everything works now. Except that i get

```
warning qapplication was not created in the main()
```

Despite everything works anyway, i decided to move it into the main

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
browser = Browser(queue_in, queue_out)
app.exec_()
```

and run parser part in a separate process.

UPD

Figured how to run QApplication in a process

```
class QtApp(QtGui.QApplication):
"""
docstring
"""
def __init__(self, args, url_queue, filename_queue):
    QtGui.QApplication.__init__(self, args)
    browser = Browser(url_queue, filename_queue)
    self.exec_()

browser_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=QtApp, 
                                          args=(sys.argv, url_queue, filename_queue))
```

Answer (score 2):

`Queue.get()` blocks if the queue is empty.  Use [get_nowait()](http://devdocs.io/python/library/asyncio-sync#asyncio.Queue.get_nowait), which will raise an exception if there's nothing there.

Comment: Well. But i need my Browser to continue running at this point. So in this case i need to make an exception handler inside the process and check periodically if there is something in the queue? Maybe. I also may create another process for parsing part and don't worry about main process being blocked. This is kinda not what i wanted to know. I more interested in WHY this happening. But thank you for this workaround.